# C3 Javascript why is subchart not woking in mobile?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, responsive, c3.js

I'm using c3-d3 library to create a bar chart, in computers it works fine, I can choose the area of the subcharts and it zooms the bars, but in mobile it does not even allows me to choose the area to zoom in subchart.

This is my code:

html where is my chart

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
            <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                        <div class="ibox-title">
                            <h5>Body Mass Analysis <small>Bar Chart</small></h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ibox-content">
                             <div>
                                <div id="stocked"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

my c3 charts.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#stocked',
            data: {
                labels: ['y',1,2,3,4,5,6],
            columns: [
                ['MUSCLE', <?php echo substr($muscle,1,strlen($muscle)); ?>],
                ['FAT', <?php echo substr($fat,1,strlen($fat)); ?>]
            ],
            groups: [
                        ['MUSCLE', 'FAT']
                    ],
            type: 'bar',
            colors:{
                MUSCLE: '#75e3ff',
                FAT: '#23bbe8'

            }
            },
            bar: {
            width: { ratio: 0.8 }
            },
            axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'categories',
                show: true,
                label: {
                 text: 'Measurements',
                 position: 'outer-middle'
                },
                tick: {
                format: "%b",
                fit: true
                }
            },
            y: {
                label: {
                 text: '<?php echo $_SESSION["unit"]; ?>',
                 position: 'outer-middle'
                }
            },

            },
            subchart: {
            show: true
            }, 
            zoom: {
            enabled: true
            }
            });
```

this is how it looks, I would like to do this on mobile too.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: To zoom in with your fingers on mobile?

Comment: the area that I want to choose in subchart is not working, it does not do anything, also zoom, this property: subchart: {
   show: true
   },